# Postgres Optimizing Average operation

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, query-optimization

**This issue has been resolved**

Solution was to create an index on (listings.id, listings.lat, listings.lng). At first the planner refused to use this index in favor of a seq scan, however vacuuming the table (VACUUM calendar) resolved that. Whew.

---

I'm having issues with query speed, it takes approx. 20s run, I really need to access in a few seconds. Am I using inefficient SQL here?

```
select c.date, avg(c.price)
from calendar c
join listings l on l.id = c.listing_id
where l.lat >= 51.45 and l.lat <= 51.5
and l.lng >= -0.2 and l.lng <= -0.1
group by c.date;
```

The lat/lng are hard-coded here, in reality they are dynamic tableau parameters.

I know the lat/lng test and join onto listings is NOT the bottleneck, that runs fast. The query runs in roughly the same time without a group by as well, so I don't believe that is the bottleneck either.

To indicate size, that particular query is averaging ~230,000 rows. I have tried multi-column indexes of (c.date, c.listing_id) and (c.date, c.listing_id, c.price) without any speed improvement.

Naturally I can't pre-compute the result as the lat/lng will be different each time.

Can I improve the speed here? Do I need to upgrade my Amazon RDS instance?

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

(Using Postgres 9.5)

**Update**

From what I can tell from testing, the query is very slow because it is using a seq scan on 'calendar'. I added the index (l.id, l.lat, l.lng) and force the index usage using SET enable_seqscan = off; and the query ran in <1s. I have no idea why the optimiser is using a seq instead of index scan.

EXPLAIN ANALYZE: [with seq scan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/qTIc), [without seq scan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/M9Nb)

Comment: It *is* the `join` that is the problem.  I think you are mistaking returning the first row with returning all the entire result set.  The `group by` needs the entire result set, so it seems longer.  I would suggest looking into a GIS index.  (You'll have the same issue with an `order by`, for instance.)

Comment: The following lat/lng query only takes 500ms to run? Are you saying the issue is joining the IDs to the calendar table?

select l.id from listings l
where l.lat >= 51.45 and l.lat <= 51.5
and l.lng >= -0.2 and l.lng <= -0.1;

Comment: Do the tables have primary keys?(they should) Is there a FK constraint for the 1:N association? Is there a supporting index for the FK? Do you have statistics?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes)  and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Issue resolved, thanks for all replies.